# How exactly does Python look up an attribute on an object?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, lookup

Consider a Python object `o` of class `C`. What exactly happens when accessing `o.foo`?

Presumably the runtime first looks to see whether `o` itself contains `foo` (in its `__dict__` and/or `__slots__`), then checks `C`, then the base classes of `C`.

Is that fundamentally how attribute lookup is performed? If so, presumably the process is more complicated in practice - are other locations checked for `foo`?

Are there facilities in Python that can be used to customize the above lookup process?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that; there's a fairly complete description here: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-lookup-works.html

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by customizing the lookup?

Comment: [This is worth checking out too](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup). You've got to know about the [descriptor protocol, though](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate properly explains this; it's too bogged down in trying to validate one particular mental model.